# What is the difference between nmap -D and nmap -S?

Tags: networking, kali-linux, nmap

I am learning nmap , as per my understanding `nmap -S <IP>` is used to spoof your scan i.e. use an IP address other than your original IP address to show that the traffic was originated from the spoofed IP.

In the [Cybrary course](https://app.cybrary.it/immersive) it was mentioned, that we can use `nmap -D <i.p. address>` to fool the host machine that the IP address is the Decoy one and not your real IP.

Can somebody please help me understand the difference between the two commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal of both options is similar, however `-D` allows you to specify a number of hosts.
Therefore, according to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap#-D) the syntax is actually slightly different than outlined by you, ie `-D decoy1[,decoy2][,ME][,...]`.
This allows you to obfuscate which of the addresses that were passed is the actual source host (denoted by `ME` here) because the IDS or target host will see a number of portscans. You, on the "ME" host, will be able to retrieve the results without the target knowing which host was actually scanning.

Comment: Thank you so much!!